# Why is SSH not invoking .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, ssh

My understanding had been that `.bash_profile` would always be invoked via an SSH login.

However I am not seeing the various settings enabled unless I do the following:

```
ssh $host "source ~/.bash_profile ; echo $PATH "

.:/mnt/spark-1.4.1/bin:/mnt/spark-1.4.1/sbin:/mnt/scala-2.11.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

When I simply do:

```
ssh $host "echo $PATH "
```

The PATH info is just the default

```
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The user is root and the default shell is bash.

```
$ ll /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug  6 19:54 /bin/sh -> bash
```

**Update** root's shell **is** bash

```
grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: I just noticed this: from your examples, I'm pretty sure you have **not** been executing the commands you think you've been executing. For example, `ssh $host "echo $PATH"` will echo the local machine/account's `$PATH`, because double-quotes don't block parameter expansion or tilde expansion, so those things get expanded on the local machine before the `ssh` command is executed. If you want to see the `$PATH` for the machine you're SSHing into, you need to use single quotes around the remote command: `ssh $host 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: @Spiff Fair enough.  I wrote this nearly a month ago and have been doing   a 'better' job recently of doing the quotes properly. This morning I ran  ssh $host  'echo $SPARK_HOME'.  It was using single quotes and came back with nothing. That variable is set within .bash_profile

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SSH with a command will **NOT** start a login shell. Thus bash_profile is not sourced.

See details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332531/why-does-remote-bash-source-bash-profile-instead-of-bashrc)

Answer (score 7):

Do you have a `.bashrc` file set? It could be damaged or corrupted or has something that causes the processing of `.bashrc` to choke and fail. And as a result, the doesn’t get to the point where it can cleanly digest/process `.bash_profile`.

As shown [on this site](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/), `.bashrc` loads before `.bash_profile`:

|  | Interactive login | Interactive non-login | Script |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `/etc/profile` | A |  |  |
| `/etc/bash.bashrc` |  | A |  |
| `~/.bashrc` |  | B |  |
| `~/.bash_profile` | B1 |  |  |
| `~/.bash_login` | B2 |  |  |
| `~/.profile` | B3 |  |  |
| `BASH_ENV` |  |  | A |
| `~/.bash_logout` | C |  |  |

I would recommend checking that `.bashrc` and maybe even temporarily renaming it something like `.bashrc_off` to disable it to test the theory before debugging any further.

Comment: Zero ~/.bashrc , /etc/bash.bashrc , ~/.bash_login , ~/.profile on these systems. Only ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bash_logout

Comment: Thanks, this is an AMI for Spark for which I did not touch /etc/profile  -and which looks pretty generic.  There is no  /etc/.bash.bashrc.

Comment: Do you mind taking a look, i have updated the OP. This problem is killing me - since without .bash_profile there is NO way for me to set up the remote ssh environment.

Answer (score 2):

add `-l` may be an easy workaround, `-l` option makes bash act as a login shell, a login shell will execute .bash_profile.

```
ssh $host bash -l -c single_word_command
```

or

```
ssh $host bash -l -c '"commands with space"'
```

because `$` sign needs escape, to echo $PATH some additional work is needed, something like

```
ssh $host bash -l -c "'echo \$PATH'"
```

the `\` before `$` prevent "local" shell to replace $PATH to real value, the `'` in `"` is needed because outer `"` is removed after sending to "remote"

by the way
`ssh -v` and `bash -v` is very helpful for debugging escape things like this

Answer (score 1):

What was that last bit about `/bin/sh`? If root's default shell is set to `/bin/sh`, then `bash` will be invoked in POSIX Bourne shell compatibility mode, where `bash`-specific startup scripts will not be run.

Comment: That was a commentary that /bin/sh is symlinked to bash on the system - in case ssh defaults to using /bin/sh (which I am uncertain about).

Comment: @javadba So go check and tell us what the root user's shell is set to on the system you're SSHing into. SSH just performs a login. The default shell of the account you're logging into is the shell that gets used. If it's set to `/bin/sh`, that's your problem. If you want to use `.bash_profile`, you have to invoke `bash` as `bash`, because `bash` looks to see whether it was invoked as `sh` and changes behavior to be more `sh`-like.

Comment: root's shell *is* bash (OP updated)